# How to check if user already rated a book

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to make a review system like Google Play for my Library app, which mean 1 user just can submit review 1 time, the next time will be edit review

https://i.stack.imgur.com/exQXl.jpg

This is what I have so far:

In Book/show.html.erb

```
     <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
      <% @book.reviews.each do |r| %>
        <div class = "reviews" >
          <div class="star-rating" data-score= <%= r.rating %></div>
          <%= link_to r.user.name, r%>
          <p><%= r.comment %></p>
        </div>
      <% end %>    
     </div>
     </div>

     <script>
 $('.star-rating').raty({
    path: '/assets/',
    readOnly: true,
    score: function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
     </script>
```

In reviews_controller

```
    def update
    @reviews = Reviews.find_by(params[:id])
    @review.update_attributes(reviews_params)
    @book  = Book.find(@review.book_id)
    flash[:success] = "Comment updated"
    redirect_to @book
    end

    def edit
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end
```

In reviews/edit.html.erb:

```
    <%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification message: 
     f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if 
     f.object.errors[:base].present? %>
    <div class="field">
    <div id="star-rating"></div>
    </div>
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment, class: 'text-area' %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :book_id%>
   <div>

   <div class="form-actions">
   <%= f.button :submit, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
   </div>
   <% end %>
   <script>
   $('#star-rating').raty({
    path: '/assets/',
    scoreName: 'review[rating]'
   });
   </script>
```

I don't know if rails have a function to check the  current user's id with the user review's id for that book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to add a validation constraint on your review model.

```
class Review
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book

  validates :book_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
end
```

The validation clause can be read as "validate the uniqueness of book_id for a given user_id".

So validation will be false if a user tries to create a review for a book he/she already reviewed.

Comment: well if it does, don't forget to upvote/accept the solution ;)